# using subprocess for sequence of terminal commands

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I'm attempting to make my first program, im automating the git push / clone processes using GUI inputs.

```
    """GUI GIT Program"""
#Import Statements
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import subprocess
from time import sleep

# set up the GUI
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Git Handler")
w.pack()

# Welcome the User
messagebox.showinfo("Welcome","This is a program to automate your Git stuff!")

# solicit input
user_name = simpledialog.askstring("Username:","What is your username?")
password = simpledialog.askstring("Password","What is your password?",show="*")
message_for_push = simpledialog.askstring("Push Message","What's your push message?")

# do stuff with the data
# call(["git","push"])
# sleep (2)
# call([user_name])
# sleep (2)
# call([password])
commands = '''
git push'''
user_name
password


process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate(commands.encode('utf-8'))
print(out.decode('utf-8'))
```

The issue im having is that the git push command executes, but the next step enter user name doesnt, and all subsequent commands as well... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue long time back, and was able to get around with below code snippet.

```
git-clone () {
    print "Bitbucket checkout enter bitbucket user/pass."
    echo -n "Bitbucket username:"
    read bit_user
    #echo "Bitbucket pass:"
    read -s -p "Bitbucket Password:" bit_pass
    su -c "cd /home/latlongo; git clone https://$bit_user:$bit_pass@bitbucket.org/xyz.git -b your_branch" -m $1
}
```

Comment: so ... sorry being the noob i am, is this just for the cloning process? and also, whats bitbucket?

Comment: yes this is for cloning, but you can replace 'git clone' command with any other git command. Bitbucket is you can consider like commercial git from Atlassian.

Comment: getting some errors its not liking the curly brackets? i should add im using python 3